# How to import my mongo db from my local to a remote linux server

Tags: database, mongodb, import, mongorestore

I have already export my mongo databse using mongodump and i already have a copy of the folder. Now I want import and use that database to my server which is a linux server , Dont worry I am already connected to the server , I wanted to know how to import mongo db to the server. Import whole collections into a single databsae,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore backup using [**MongoRestore**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/). Please follow the official documentation there.

If your backup is simply in BSON files:

```
mongorestore --host <host-name> --db <db-name> <directory-to-bsonfiles>
//e.g. in case your backup files are in director /home/mongo/backup/<bson files>
mongorestore --db test_db /home/mongo/backup/
//In case mongo server running on particular replicaset, host and port;
mongorestore --host "rs0/11.22.33.44:37568" --db test_db /home/mongo/backup/
//In case you want to restore particular collection only;
mongorestore --db test_db --collection test_collection /home/mongo/backup/test_collection.bson
```

In case your backup is saved as archived (e.g. gzip, tar etc.)

```
mongorestore --db test_db --gzip --archive=/home/mongo/backup/test_db-dump-2019-08-08.gzip
```

Comment: is this ip address "rs0/11.22.33.44:37568"?

Comment: can we restore the databse from my ip address to the servers ip address?

Comment: There is no direct way to backup data from local machine to remote machine. However, you can first copy the backup data to remote machine (e.g. `scp`) and then execute the restore command in remote machine (eg. using `ssh` tunneling). Yes, `"rs0/11.22.33.44:37568"` is example of remote address of host machine where `mongodb` server is running on particular replicaSet `rs0` (`localhost:27017` is local address of mongo server on default port)

Comment: ah i see , i got it bro ill try

Comment: i got an error [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before                                       statement @(shell):1:15

Comment: i used this command mongorestore --db machaik --zip --archive=/home/ftsi/machaik/machaik.zip

Comment: The dump file must be archive file that has been exported using `mongodump` command. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#compress-the-output

Comment: Yeah i did got it from a dump and then i zip it.

Comment: cause you say incase backup is archived

Comment: No, you cannot zip the dump files. It must be exported as archive file(gzip) while dumping via `mongodump`. Please, follow the documentation for `mongodump`. You will have more information there - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#mongodump